# T-SQL Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string only on View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use a T-SQL query to get data from the past week. I have view which returns the following columns:

```
Name (varchar) 
Date Registered (DateTime)
```

I am trying to use the view to only get the last weeks data. However, I keep getting the error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here's my sql:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @6DaysAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-6,@Now);

SELECT * 
FROM vw_Logs l
WHERE convert(DATETIME, 'l.Date Registered', 121) BETWEEN @6DaysAgo and @Now
```

When I write the exact same SQL statement, using the table instead of the view, I do not get an error.

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @6DaysAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-6,@Now);

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_Logs l
WHERE convert(DATETIME, l.DateRegistered, 121) BETWEEN @6DaysAgo and @Now
```

I suspect it has something to do with the column names? The view has a space (`Date Registered`) and the table does not (`DateRegistered`).

Is this the case? If so, how can I get the last weeks data from the view w/o changing the column name?

Comment: You try to convert the string 'l.Date Registered' to a datetime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here. First, why do you convert DateRegistered to a datetime? You stated it is already a datetime column right? Formatting it isn't going to make any difference when doing a comparison. It does however render your query nonSARGable and any indexes are that column are now ignored.

The second issue I see is that I am guessing you want anything within the last 6 days. The way you have this coded it is not accurate. Your calculation will exclude any rows that happened on that day before the current time of day.

Look at the values of your variables.

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @6DaysAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-6,@Now);

select @Now, @6DaysAgo
```

Instead you could do something like this. It is SARGable and it does not have the issue of the timestamp.

```
SELECT [Column List]
FROM vw_Logs l 
WHERE l.[Date Registered] > dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()) - 6, 0) 
and l.[Date Registered] < GETDATE()
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out that I will be getting the wrong data back. I am taking a look into that now.

Comment: I updated my variables to the following: `DECLARE @Tomorrow DATETIME = DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE());
DECLARE @8DaysAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-8,@Tomorrow);`

Comment: You will still have the time of day issue. This may or may not be acceptable depending on your requirements. The code I posted above will get you data since the beginning of that day. In other words it will change the time portion of your datetime variable to 00:00:00.000

Comment: ah...I see. I've used your query, and am now getting this error: `Incorrect syntax near '0'.`

Comment: Oh yes indeed you would. I left out a comma. Stupid computer keeps doing what I tell it, not what I want. :) My code above has been edited so it should work now. Sorry about that.

Comment: That worked out nicely. Thanks so much for pointing out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's **not** the exact same SQL statement! You need to enclose your column name with a space in it in your view in square brackets - not single quotes:

```
SELECT * 
FROM vw_Logs l
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, l.[Date Registered], 121) BETWEEN @6DaysAgo AND @Now
```

Putting that expression in single quotes makes it a string literal, and a string literal which really doesn't convert well into a `DATETIME` ....